# What is the output speed of a Unix/Linux terminal?

Tags: c++, terminal, output

I'm trying to do a simple experiment, determining the difference in performance between using `cout << 'c'` and `cout << "c"` to print a single character 'c' (or any other characters).

I plan to put the `cout` statement in a loop, let it run for thousands of times repeatedly, and measure how much time it consumes. But before that, I wonder if the output speed of my terminal will limit the execution speed of the `cout` statement, which would affect the accuracy of the experiment. And if so, how can I set up another experiment to achieve my goal?

BTW, I'm going to do this experiment on a Mac with iTerm2.

Comment: Redirect your output to `/dev/null` if you don't want the speed of the terminal to come into it?

Comment: Remember to set [`std::cout.sync_with_stdio(false);`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/sync_with_stdio) and make sure the compiler won't do funny things with your for-loop (like combining the output statements, if it's smart enough).

Comment: @Arkku I think that would be a good solution. But I'm still curious about the actual output speed of a terminal.

Comment: @lei.april Yes, well, I don't have a very good answer to that, which is why I posted that suggestion as a comment and not an answer. =) But, very generally speaking, different terminals have different speeds (and it can even depend on whether or not the terminal window is visible on screen).

Comment: Most likely your question should be - What is the output speed of iTerm2 - also it will vary greatly beased on buffer size, smooth scrolling and other terminal settings.

Comment: @DyP I just tried your solution. But there seems to be some problem with it. I set the number of iterations to 100,000,000. When I redirect stdout to `/dev/null`, it takes about 5 seconds for each outputting method to finish. But when I just set `cout.sync_with_stdio(false)` without redirecting stdout, it takes about 15 seconds, which is significantly slower. Any idea about this?

Comment: @lei.april The `sync_with_stdio` is just *one* thing you should do to improve performance - namely eliminating some synchronization with the C streams, and allowing for buffering. It can always be used if you don't use the C streams in that application. *Another*, and unrelated speed-up can be gained by redirecting to `/dev/null` (if you don't care about the actual output). I.e. you can combine the two.

Comment: @DyP I tried again, without redirecting stdout or setting `cout.sync_with_stdio(false)`. But there's no distinct difference in the execution time. It seems that function just has no effect. I don't quite understand how it works.

Comment: @lei.april As described at the [linked description](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/sync_with_stdio), 1) it should be called before *any* I/O has taken place and 2) it depends on your implementation (your compiler + Standard Library implementation) if it provides any benefit. What it does: Normally, the C streams (`stdin` etc., as used by e.g. `printf`) are synchronized with the C++ streams (`std::cin` etc.). `sync_with_stdio(false)` may disable this synchronization, which *can* (and typically does) lead to a performance boost. (compile with optimizations enabled!)

Comment: @DyP I put `cout.sync_with_stdio(false)` into the loop, and turned on the `-O2` compiler option. But the result is still no different. BTW, the compiler is clang 3.3